# Replace Kendo default dropdownlist template by custom image?

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, background-image

What I want to do is when i click on my image, i want the kendo dorpdownlist to propose me some options. Is it possible ?

I tried to replace the defautl template of dropdownlist with CSS without success.

Here i try simply to replace the default black arrow of the dropdownlist, with no success.
SOURCE : http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/appearance-styling?x=54&y=12

-----------------------------HTML

```
<select id="customList" class="k-widget k-dropdown"></select>
```

-----------------------------Javascript

```
$("#customList").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");
```

-----------------------------CSS

```
#customList .k-icon .k-i-arrow-s
{
    background-image:url('../../resources/img/components/addtab.png');
}
```

But what i really want to achieve is to replace completely the default template of the kendo dropdownlist and to have instead my image.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code that you tried?

Comment: Sorry. The initial post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of question to keep in mind:

1. The HTML element that contains the arrow is not a descendant of `customList` but descendant of a sibling. This is because KendoUI *decorates* original elements with others.
2. You are only re-defining `background-image` but you there is two additional CSS attributes that you need to redefine: `background-position` and `background-size` since it is defined in Kendo UI CSS files for offsetting `k-i-arrow-s` icon.

So, you should either do:

```
span.k-icon.k-i-arrow-s {
    background-image:url('../../resources/img/components/addtab.png');
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

if you are ok with redefining every additional elements **OR** you do it programmatically defining a CSS:

```
.ob-style {
    background-image:url('../../resources/img/components/addtab.png');
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

and a JavaScript:

```
var list = $("#customList").kendoDropDownList({...}).data("kendoDropDownList");
$(list.wrapper).find(".k-icon.k-i-arrow-s").addClass("ob-style");
```